# Travel in the Lord of the Rings LCG?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

I'm never quite sure how this phase of each round is supposed to go...

So, say during the quest phase you encounter a location with 2 quest points, and after you resolve the quest you come out +2. Do you put the progress tokens on the **quest** card and then travel to the location? *or* do you travel to the location and put them on the **location** card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an "active" location, you place progress on it before you place them on the current quest.  But a location only becomes active when you travel to it.  If you just revealed the location, it is still in the staging area and not active, so you would put the progress on the quest.  You may then choose to travel to the location during the travel phase.